# Why series over NumPy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, series

Series are labeled 1d array and we have arrays in NumPy in general. Why should I use one over the other? Also I came across these statements while looking for answers:

> Pandas Series are designed to handle labeled data. Each element in a
> Series has a label (an index), which makes it easy to associate data
> with meaningful labels or names.

> Pandas Series automatically align data based on their labels when
> performing operations like addition, subtraction, or joining. This
> alignment can be very useful when dealing with data from different
> sources.

I don't think I understand. Especially the first point about labeling. I mean, yeah we can see the labels in Series, but what is meant by *"designated to handle labeled data"*? How am I supposed to know what data is labeled? Are data having indices enough to call them labeled data? Then arrays in general has indices associated with elements, what about that?

About the second statement too, don't arrays in general align data with their label (indices)? For example, in NumPy when I'm applying an ufunc on the array, it's performing the task based on the alignment, or no?

Comment: Consider this example `pd.concat([pd.Series([10, 20], index=[1, 2]), pd.Series([30, 40], index=[2, 1])], axis=1)`. What is the expected result? Do you see how the indices of the two series align?

Answer (score 4):

The alignment wording may be a bit awkward - what they mean is that in pandas, rows are associated by like values in an index column (the labels), which may not be integers in a simple numerical order 0, 1, 2, etc...

In numpy, there is no explicit index. When you specify an index, numpy does a simple calculation based on the size of the contained object and its dimensions to locate a value's position in memory.

Suppose I have information about farm animals from several sources, but these sources list the animals in a different order. Pandas will match `Series` values by the values in the index (the labels). "cows" goes to "cows" in the other array, regardless of position.

pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], 
    index=["cows", "pigs", "horses", "goats"])
df2 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], 
    index=["goats", "horses", "pigs", "cows"])
print("series")
print(df1 + df2)
```

Output

```
series
cows      5
goats     5
horses    5
pigs      5
dtype: int64
```

numpy would lose the association between the named animal and its value and would naively perform operations based on position.

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
arr2 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print("array")
print(arr1 + arr2)
```

Output

```
array
[2 4 6 8]
```

numpy is generally faster while pandas is more feature rich.